# Bootstrap popover template loses knockout bindings

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

I'm trying to make a popover which has a html-form and a button with type "submit". This popover is also bound to knockout.js.

When I click the button on the popover, it does not trigger the KO function, instead it makes a standard post request.

If I move my form to outside of the popover, it works fine.

How can I create a html-form in a popover and trigger a function of my model with submit button?

Here is a [non-working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmet229/jkfbbbe9/)

```html
<a href="#" id="createTaskPopover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Create Task">Click me!!!</a>

<div id="createTaskPopoverContent" class="hide">
    <form data-bind="submit: AddTask">
        <input type="hidden" id="FeatureId" name="FeatureId" value="" />
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" style="width:100%;" /><br />

        <br />
        <button id="btnCreateNewTask" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create</button>
        <br />
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
$('#createTaskPopover').popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: 'true',
        content: function () {
            return $("#createTaskPopoverContent").html();
        }
    });

function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.AddTask = function (formElement) {
        console.log(formElement);
    }
}
var projectVM = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(projectVM);
```

Comment: You may be interested to look at [knockstrap](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/) which helps bridge the gap between Bootstrap and Knockout.  It's got a [specific binding](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/#popover) for popovers.

Comment: I think, there should be a way, without using any extension. It is not a rare problem I have faced.

Comment: Oh yes - it's certainly not an answer to your question, but it's handy to know these things exist sometimes :)  Looking at your specific problem, I think it's because you're dynamically returning the content of the popup using `.html()`, so it's losing the `submit` binding at that point.  I don't have a workaround as yet though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you're duplicating the html with the `.html()` call, at which point the knockout bindings are lost.  You can actually give bootstrap the element to use directly, and coupled with the shown event to remove the `hide` class, it works as you want it to:

```
$('#createTaskPopover').popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: 'true',
    content: $("#createTaskPopoverContent") //return element directly
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#createTaskPopoverContent').removeClass('hide'); //remove hide when popover shown
});
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t10vh19/).  Note however that you see a slight flicker when the popover opens while it "unhides" the content.

This can be further improved by passing just the inner `form` (or you could wrap it in another `div` if you want) to the popover, and then you don't even need to handle the shown event, and you don't see the content "appearing" once the popover has shown:

```
$('#createTaskPopover').popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: 'true',
    content: $("#createTaskPopoverContent > form") //select the form directly
});
```

[Further updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t10vh19/2/).

Comment: That is the answer of my question. Thanks for your help. +1 is also for your further improvement. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JustAnotherCodeLover No problem!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the function isn't triggered is because the HTML the popover uses is injected at runtime and Knockout bindings have been applied already:

```
content: function () {
           return $("#createTaskPopoverContent").html();
         }
```

Option A: Do Knockout binding once the popover has shown

```
$('#createTaskPopover').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  var projectVM = new VM();
  ko.applyBindings(projectVM);
})
```

Option B: Inline the HTML and simplify to `$('#createTaskPopover').popover()`

```
data-content="raw HTML here" data-html="true"
```

Comment: Option A might not work on a larger scale knockout based website - I suspect the OP will have other things being driven by knockout outside of this popover.  Will Option B even do any knockout data binding?  I suspect it'll have the exact same issues as the current code.

Comment: Option A is very difficult to be applied, due to the reason as James said. For Option B; it makes code hard to read and maintenance will be a problem. In real scenario,  my raw HTML is not simple as on this example.

Comment: Yes this is only to illustrate the point, and it's possible to separate vm's and bindings too. Clarified the second option.